# convert equations from 1+j+k format and finding area

Tags: multivariable-calculus, area

The specific problem is:
find the area of a triangle having the vertices $C(1,0,1)$, $B(0,2,3)$, and $A(-1,5,-2)$.

I've tried this so far:
obtained the vectors $BA (-1,3,-5)$ and $BC (1,-2,-2)$
The cross product (matrix part) got me $4i-3j-k$ (if someone could double check that as well)

Anyways, I know that the process is the same as a parallelogram but the answer is divided by 2. I don't know where to go from $4i-3j-k$

finally can someone can teach me to convert i+j+k into a vector where it looks like v = $<x,y,z>$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$v = <x,y,z> = xi + yj + zk$

The magnitude of the cross product is the area of the parallelogram, so you should take the magnitude of your vector ($\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$) and divide it by 2.